# Способы создания обьектов класса С++

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, объекты

Сколькими способами можно создать обьект класса на С++ в ООП?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть четыре вида длительности хранения памяти под объект (storage duration), и соответственно четыре способа создать объект:

- статическая, `static T variable(expression)`,
- потока, `thread_local T variable(expression)`,
- автоматическая, `T variable(expression)`,
- динамическая, `new T(expression)`.

Comment: Замечу, что в разных контекстах третья запись может означать разную *storage duration*.

Answer (score 1):

Экземпляр класса (объект) можно создать, выделив ему кусочек памяти, в котором поместятся значения его полей. А вот где будет этот кусочек памяти - зависит от вас.

Так что ответ:

**Технически** - одним, выделяется память, инициализируются поля, вызывается конструктор (если таковой имеется)

Но тем не менее, объект может находиться как на куче, так и на стеке.

Может будет полезно: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248703/creating-an-instance-of-class

Answer (score 0):

Оператор new имеет три разновидности:

1. бросающий исключение, если памяти не хватает

> (replaceable allocation functions)

```
new T()
```

2. НЕ бросающий исключение, если памяти не хватает

> (replaceable non-throwing allocation functions)

```
new T(std::nothrow)
```

3. И который использует какой-либо буфер памяти

> (non-allocating placement allocation functions)

```
void *raw = malloc(sizeof(int));
int *pint = new(raw) int(10);
```

Можно почитать об этом в документации: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: Но ведь экземпляр класса можно создать не только с помощью этого оператора.